# CKEditor getEditor() Error, How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ckeditor

```html
<textarea cols="50" id="txt" contenteditable="true" name="editor1" runat="server" rows="10"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css-js/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace('txt', {                    
  });       
</script>
```

I get this err on js :

> TypeError: Cannot call method `'getEditor'` of undefined

Comment: what browsers did you try this? try it on several browsers.

Comment: @AmirNoori Google Chrome Version:29.0.1547.76 and I tried also firefox and ie 10 but  not working

Comment: try to load ckeditor in a single empty html page and use it agian to see if you have any error.

Comment: Use CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'txt' ); for Div elements

Answer (score 17):

First of all, `contenteditable="true"` tag is totally invalid and obsolete in your case. Such attribute is relevant for [inline instances only](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline-section-1) and, as `<textarea>` is not (content)editable, [you don't need it](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed).

Anyway, (even if buggy) your code works for me like a charm ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/XaGYX/)). As a word of explanation, the error you see is produced when there's no element of an `id` passed to `CKEDITOR.replace()`, i.e:

```
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'bar' ); // <textarea> is #foo, error will be thrown
</script>
```

Make sure your DOM is valid and `<textarea>` exist when `CKEDITOR.replace` is called (working async?).

Comment: The code in answer does not work because **textarea does not have an ID**.

Comment: solution ```<textarea> is #foo, error will be thrown```

Comment: `document.contains(CKEDITOR.instances[inputId].element.$)` - this must be your amulet if u wanna have a deal with CKE, like check it at least once in msec

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'txt' ); for DOM elements

CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea' ); for textarea
```

Ok dude try this also

the functions appendTo and replace are all located in themedui.js file

try adding it separately,here is the link

http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/ckeditor.html#CKEDITOR

Comment: I tried both of them but it is not working I got same error. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to get rid of that, use

```
try{CKEDITOR.replace('body')}catch{}
```

it will cause CKEDITOR to open where you want it to

Comment: This should be the answer since it actually corrected the OP issue. The other answers were explanations and suggestions. Not fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and sorted it by doing the following;

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    if($("textarea").length > 0){
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in included:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Try to remove it. This can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct way to do it**  (I found this method by inspecting django admin )

```
var textAreaEl = document.getElementById("id_html_txt")
var textAreadData = textAreaEl.dataset.config

var textEditor = CKEDITOR.replace(textAreaEl, textAreadData);
textEditor.insertHtml(textAreaEl)
```

- Above configuration is for modal form but will work for normal form as well

Answer (score 0):

for vanilla js

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
   if(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').length > 0){
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' ); 
   }
</script>
```